# How to update multiple state properties with immer.js

Tags: reactjs, redux, immer.js

I wonder if it is possible to update multiple properties of state with `immer.js` in one "call".

Say I have `state`:

```
export const initialState = {
  isUserLogged: false,
  menuIsClosed: false,
  mobileMenuIsClosed: true,
  dataArray: ["dog","cat"],
};
```

And `action creator`:

```
export function updateSearchPage(data) {
  return {
    type: UPDATE_SEARCH_PAGE,
    payload: data
  };
}
```

I then use that `action creator` in React component like this:

```
  this.props.updateSearchPage({
    isUserLogged: true,
    menuIsClosed: true,
    dataArray: ["dog","cat","owl"]
  })
```

The idea is that I want to update several properties of state at the same time. But I dont know which properties it is in advance. I know how to do it with a simple reducer:

```
case UPDATE_SEARCH_PAGE:
  return Object.assign({}, state, action.payload)
```

But `how to update several properties of state with immer at the same time`? When the state properties (which one should update) are **unknown** in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can cycle on `action.payload` like the following:

```
const yourReducer = (state, action) =>
  produce(state, draft => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case UPDATE_SEARCH_PAGE:
        Object.entries(action.payload).forEach(([k, v]) => {
          draft[k] = v;
        })
        break;
    // ... other
    }
  }
```

Also: remember that on recent versions of immer is perfectly legit to returns an object, so doing `return Object.assign({}, state, action.payload)` is still valid inside a `produce` call.

Comment: Ok thx, can you please update your answer regarding Object.assign, with example inside `produce`? :)

Comment: Done... but it's clearly documented on the immer's doc: https://github.com/mweststrate/immer#reducer-example

Comment: Thanks for the link and answer.

Comment: just a question, what is the best way to restore initialState with Immer? Like `draft = undefined` or `draft = initialState` , when `case RESET_SEARCH_PAGE`?

Comment: Just `return initialState` for what I wrote at the bottom of the answer

Comment: So you mean `case RESET_SEARCH_PAGE:
        Object.assign({}, state, initialState );
        break;` ? So `state` here and not `draft`, correct?

Comment: If I get your question: just `case RESET_SEARCH_PAGE: return initialState;`

Answer (score 4):

With ES6 you can do it this way:

```js
export const state = produce((draft, action) => {
  switch (type) {
    case UPDATE_SEARCH_PAGE:
      return {...draft, ...action.payload}
  }
}, initialState)
```

In this case it works the same way as without Immer. All properties will be merged (shallow merge) into state. If you need to replace the state just return `action.payload`

Answer (score 2):

Immer gives you a draft state that you can edit. Behind the scenes it uses ES6 proxies to discover what you changed and apply in an immutable way your edits to the original state.

Basically, you can do the exact same thing you do right now, but using the Immer api:

```
import produce from 'immer'

const newState = produce(this.state, draft => Object.assign({}, draft, payload))
```

If you, instead, know what properties are changed, you can do something like:

```
const newState = produce(this.state, draft => {
  draft.propertyOne = 'newValue'
  draft.propertyTwo = 42
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @0xc14m1z, I think the the assignment of props to `draft` should be `Object.assign({draft, payload)`. i.e. you can update the `draft` directly.